# How to convert dataframe into dictionary python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Total_Time_words    Words
0      1.50         your
1      2.15         intention
2      2.75         is
3      3.40         dangerous
4      3.85         for
```

when I use this code:

```
new.set_index('Words').T.to_dict('records')
```

I get this output below:

```
[{'your': 1.5,
  'intention': 2.15,
  'is': 2.75,
  'dangerous': 3.4,
  'for': 3.85,
  'my': 4.0,
  'world': 4.3}]
```

But this is my expected output below:

```
[
   {
      1.50:"your"
   },
   
   {
      2.15:"intention"
   }
]
```

Comment: Is it json format?

Comment: dataframe, i want to convert the dataframe to ordinary dictionary {'your': 1.5},
 { 'intention': 2.15}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` with `zip` as below:

```
new_dict = [{k:v} for k,v in zip(df["Total_Time_words"], df["words"])]
print(new_dict)
```